# How do I find a higher dimensional representation of a group, which is not just a direct sum of its irreps?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Usually the dihedral groups have at most 2 dimensional irreducible representation. I guess I can just construct a >2 dimensional representation just by sticking the 2D one in block diagonal form (direct sum).

But is this the only way? Can a, say, 4 dimensional representation of $D_5$ be derived in another way?

Comment: Over fields other than  $\Bbb C$ and $\Bbb R$ can have higher-dimensional irreps, but in characteristic zero complete reducibility still applies. For example, over $\Bbb Q$, $D_5$ has a four-dimensional irrep.

Comment: Do you a link where they show what the 4D representation of $D_5$ is?

Comment: You can just decompose the regular representation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, any finite-dimensional representation of a finite group [decomposes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maschke%27s_theorem) into the direct sum of irreducible representations (over $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{C}$, or any field of characteristic zero).  Furthermore, there are only finitely many irreducible representations.

For the case of the dihedral groups, [all the irreducible real representations have dimension 1 or 2](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Linear_representation_theory_of_dihedral_groups).  So you won't get any other real representations other than by taking direct sums of these.